# Can't Resolve Symbol Drawable on Array

Tags: java, android

I have an code on Android Studio, like this:

```
public static void getData() {
        List<Information> data = new ArrayList<>();
        int[] icons = (R.drawable.ic_bookmark1, R.drawable.ic_bookmark2);
    }
```

I got an error on line:

```
 int[] icons = (R.drawable.ic_bookmark1, R.drawable.ic_bookmark2);
```

The error said on:

```
Can't resolve Symbol Drawable.
```

And also error said on:

```
 Can't resolve Symbol ic_bookmark2;
```

Screenshot:
I have put my icon in res folder

[image: I have put my icon in res folder]

The code and error

[image: The code and error line]

This is the full code of my .java file.

```
package com.balinez.wdharmana.doahindu;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME="testpref";
    public static final String KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER="user_learned_drawer";
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private BalinezAdapter adapter;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    private View containerView;

    public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mUserLearnedDrawer=Boolean.valueOf(readFromPreferences(getActivity(), KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER,"false"));

        if(savedInstanceState!=null) {
            mFromSavedInstanceState=true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.drawer_list);
        return layout;
    }

    public static void getData() {
        List<Information> data = new ArrayList<>();
        int[] icons = (R.drawable.ic_bookmark1, R.drawable.ic_bookmark1);
    }
    public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar) {
        containerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if(!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                    mUserLearnedDrawer=true;
                    saveToPreferences(getActivity(),KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER,mUserLearnedDrawer+"");
                }
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };

        if(!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(containerView);
        }

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

    }

    public static void saveToPreferences(Context context, String preferenceName, String preferenceValue) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(preferenceName,preferenceValue);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public static String readFromPreferences(Context context, String preferenceName, String defaultValue) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getString(preferenceName, defaultValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have you drawable folder under the res folder? And did you _really_ put ic_bookmark1 and ic_bbokmark2 into the drawable folder?

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding?

Comment: i have try. doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue lies in the use of parentheses and you should be using brackets.

```
int[] icons = (R.drawable.ic_bookmark1, R.drawable.ic_bookmark2);
```

should be

```
int[] icons = {R.drawable.ic_bookmark1, R.drawable.ic_bookmark2};
```

Comment: IT WORKS!! Thanks Nate :)